# How do I fix a technical drawing pen with a bent needle?

Tags: drafting

I accidentally dropped my [Mars Matic 0.5mm](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001U3RCGQ) and noticed that maybe I broke the needle. I was having a hard time writing with it so I tried to clean it, and while cleaning I accidentally bent the needle part. After all the trouble that I experienced I manage to straighten the needle very carefully.

Right now it's working fine but I need to shake it rigorously. I am planning on buying a new one because of the hassle of using it but there is also a side of me that says I should not buy a new one.

Is there any other way that I can fix my pen? It's slightly bent now but by shaking it rigorously it can still write.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is my second question in this site and I would like the community to know that I am really grateful about the help of this community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buy a replacement nib. The following picture is from eBay. I just wanted a picture to show you that it is possible to remove the existing nib and replace it.

I would suggest you make enquires with pen supplier, or search the internet for a replacement nib.

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks! This is what I'm looking for. Also, the picture helps me to realize that the nib can be removed. Thanks!